# Declaration or statement expected in If Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I am working on some code to build a simple application in Javascript where the computer has a random number assigned to rock, paper, scissors and choose randomly and then has a userchoice as well. The code is not running not sure why.

I have tried adding semicolon to the end of the if statements that are inside the main if statement in the determineWinner function.

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors'){
    return userInput;
  }else {
    console.log('Error, you must type rock, paper, or scissors');
  }
}

function getComputerChoice(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock';
    case 1:
      return 'paper';
    case 2:
      return 'scissors';
  }
}

function determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice){
  if(userChoice === computerChoice){
    return 'This game is a tie!'
  } else if(userChoice === 'rock'){
      if(computerChoice === 'paper'){
        return 'The computer has won!';
    }else{
      return 'The user has won';
    }
  } else if(userChoice === 'paper'){
      if(computerChoice === 'scissors'){
        return 'The computer has won!';
      }else(computerChoice === 'rock');{
        return 'The user has won!';
      }
    }else(userChoice === 'scissors');{
      if(computerChoice === 'rock'){
        return 'The computer has won!';
      }else(computerChoice === 'paper');{
        return 'The user has won!';
        }
    }
  } 
}

console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'scissors'));
```

When running the console.log at the end of the script it should display that the computer has won.

Comment: Either you use `else` with no condition, or `else if` with a condition. You can't mix and match. And don't sprinkle `;` randomly, understand the syntax. Details matter.

Comment: I am new, but from my understanding you can only use else at the end of an if statement you can't use else if?

Comment: @mildlylost You can use `else if` at the end. For example `if(i < -5) { ... } else if(i > 5) { ... }` is valid, it only treats `i`s that are either less than `-5` or greater than `5`, `i`s that are between `-5` and `5` will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of your `if` cases simply return, you don't need to use `else` since the if-case will always return. Like this:

```
function determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice){
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 'This game is a tie!'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'rock') {
    if(computerChoice === 'paper') {
      return 'The computer has won!';
    }
    return 'The user has won';
  }
  if (userChoice === 'paper') {
    if(computerChoice === 'scissors'){
      return 'The computer has won!';
    }
    return 'The user has won!';
  }
  if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
    if(computerChoice === 'rock') {
      return 'The computer has won!';
    }
    return 'The user has won!';
  } 
}
```

Another way is to just return at the end of the function with the answer like this:

```
function determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice){
  const results = [
    'This game is a tie!', 
    'The computer has won!', 
    'The user has won!' 
  ];
  let winner;
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) winner = 0;
  else if (userChoice === 'rock') {
    winner = computerChoice === 'paper' ? 1 : 2;
  }
  else if (userChoice === 'paper') {
    winner = computerChoice === 'scissors' ? 1 : 2;
  }
  else if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
    winner = computerChoice === 'rock' ? 1 : 2;
  } 
  return results[winner];
}
```

Comment: I like how you structured the second function that you wrote, I have been learning that way of doing things but not that practiced with it yet. I fixed my code will post is as an answer but mark yours as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors'){
    return userInput;
  }else {
    console.log('Error, you must type rock, paper, or scissors');
  }
}

function getComputerChoice(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock';
    case 1:
      return 'paper';
    case 2:
      return 'scissors';
  }
}

function determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice){
  if(userChoice === computerChoice){
    return 'This game is a tie!'
  } else if(userChoice === 'rock'){
      if(computerChoice === 'paper'){
        return 'The computer has won!';
    }else if(computerChoice === 'scissors'){
      return 'The user has won';
    }
  } else if(userChoice === 'paper'){
      if(computerChoice === 'scissors'){
        return 'The computer has won!';
      }else if(computerChoice === 'rock'){
        return 'The user has won!';
      }
    }else if(userChoice === 'scissors'){
      if(computerChoice === 'rock'){
        return 'The computer has won!';
      }else if(computerChoice === 'paper'){
        return 'The user has won!';
        }
    }
  } 


console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'scissors'));
```